# automatically move to n-th character on line after each C-n or C-p

Tags: key-bindings, html

this feature would go nicely with emmet mode.
With emmet-mode, I can expand

```
li*3
```

to

```
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

effortlessly.
But after i enter something in between first tags. i have to scroll to the right position on moving to next line which is inconvinient.

This lock i'm looking for would do awesome job.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`set-goal-column` might be what you're looking for :

```
set-goal-column is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
`simple.el'.

It is bound to C-x C-n.

(set-goal-column ARG)

Set the current horizontal position as a goal for C-n and C-p.
Those commands will move to this position in the line moved to
rather than trying to keep the same horizontal position.
With a non-nil argument ARG, clears out the goal column
so that C-n and C-p resume vertical motion.
The goal column is stored in the variable `goal-column'.
```